# Sum columns on different tables and multiply by value of a column on another table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to compute employees' monthly salaries based on meetings attended, deductions and bonuses given;
Employees have different pay per meeting based on their job position.

The solution is:
salary = (Pay_per_minute * meetings_attended) + bonuses - deductions ;

I have four tables:

**Jobs:** Id, title, pay_per_meeting

**Employees:** Id, Name, job_id

**Bonuses:** Id, amount, employee_id, date

**Deductions:** Id, amount, employee_id, date

**Meetings:** Id, employee_id, date

```
SELECT
COUNT(meetings.employee_id) as meetings_attended, 
COUNT(deductions.amount) as debt, 
COUNT(bonuses.amount) bonus, 
(SELECT jobs.pay_per_attendance from jobs where jobs.id = (select job_id from employees where id=meetings.employee_id)) as pay,
((meetings_attended * pay) + bonus - debt) as salary 
FROM meetings 
JOIN deductions ON deductions.employee_id = meetings.employee_id 
JOIN bonuses ON bonuses.employee_id = meetings.employee_id 
WHERE meetings.employee_id = 1 
GROUP BY MONTH(meetings.date), MONTH(deductions.date), MONTH(bonuses.date)
```

The above query returns many incorrect values whenever i remove the salary line but gives error of unknown column pay, meetings_attended, debt and bonus, am sure something is wrong with the grouping but i can't just see it.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to column aliases in the same select list as they're defined, you need to refer to the underlying column. And a subquery can't access an aggregate calculated in the main query. You need to repeat the aggregate expression, or move everything into a subquery and do the calculation with it in an outer query.

Also, all your `COUNT()` expressions are going to return the same thing, since they're just counting rows (I assume none of the values can be `NULL`). You probably want `COUNT(DISTINCT <column>)` to get different counts, and you need to use a column that's unique, so they should be the primary key column, e.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT deductions.id)`.

Another problem is that when you try to sum and count values when you have multiple joins, you end up with a result that's too high, because rows get duplicated in the cross product of all the tables. See [Join tables with SUM issue in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978511/join-tables-with-sum-issue-in-mysql/37979049#37979049). The solution is to calculate the sums from each table in subqueries.

```
SELECT m.month, m.meetings_attended, d.debt, b.bonus, 
    m.meetings_attended * j.pay_per_meeting + b.amount - d.amount AS salary
FROM (
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS meetings_attended
    FROM meetings
    WHERE employee_id = 1
    GROUP BY month) AS m
JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS bonus, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM bonuses
    WHERE employee_id = 1
    GROUP BY month) AS b ON m.month = b.month
JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS debt, SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM deductions
    WHERE employee_id = 1
    GROUP BY month) AS d ON m.month = d.month
CROSS JOIN employees AS e
JOIN jobs AS j ON j.id = e.job_id
WHERE e.employee_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! However am getting this error **"Unknown column 'j.pay_per_meeting' in 'field list'"**

Comment: You wrote: `Jobs: Id, title, pay_per_meeting` so isn't that the name of the column? Or is it `pay_per_attendance` like you wrote in your query?