# Connecting two mySQL tables and and summarising with unique values

Tags: mysql

I've got two `mySQL` tables, *Table A and B*. I need to get an output like in Table 3.

Below mentioned is the code I tried with Full Join and does not give me the intended result. Much appreciate your help..

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Table_A.Code) as 'Code', SUM(Table_A.Qty_On_Hand) as 'On Hand Qty', SUM(Table_B.Counted_Qty) as 'Counted Qty'
FULL JOIN Table_B ON Table_A.Code = Table_B.Code
FROM Table_A
```

Table A

| Code | On Hand Qty |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 10 |
| B | 20 |
| B | 50 |
| C | 60 |

Table B

| Code | Counted Qty |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 30 |
| B | 0 |
| C | 10 |

Out put required:

| Code | On Hand Qty | Counted Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 10 |
| B | 80 | 0 |
| C | 60 | 40 |

Comment: `DISTINCT` isn't a function. It's a keyword that makes the entire select list unique, it doesn't apply to a specific column.

Comment: That required output seems to be incorrect. Shouldn't the `Counted Qty` column for `C` return `40`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY Table_A.Code`, not `DISTINCT`.

```
SELECT a.Code, SUM(a.Qty_On_Hand) AS `On Hand Qty`, b.`Counted Qty`
FROM Table_A as a
JOIN (
    SELECT Code, SUM(Counted_Qty) AS `Counted Qty`
    FROM Table_B
    GROUP BY Code
) AS b ON a.Code = b.Code
GROUP BY a.Code
```

You need to do one of the `SUMs` in a subquery, otherwise you'll multiply its sums by the number of rows in the other table. See [Join tables with SUM issue in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978511/join-tables-with-sum-issue-in-mysql/37979049#37979049).

Comment: Thank you @Barmar. Learned something new today.